# Impact of "chmod g-w,o-w /" on a Linux System

Tags: linux, chmod

If one is on as root, and runs this:

```
chmod -R g-w,o-w /
```

What are the implications?  And what would one have to do to undo the effects?

Yes, the dumb user was me.  So we fixed it as follows:

- Add back g+w and o+w to all the "c" file types in /dev and its subdirectories.
- Add back g+w and o+w to /tmp so processes can write temp files.
- We're not worried about /home.  That was what we were attempting to modify.

And things like /usr/lib and such are already g-w and o-w.

But what other system areas my be detrimentally impacted by removing group and others write as root from the / level?

The system seems fine now, but just want to know if there is anything I'm missing that has yet to turn up.

All assistance appreciated!

Comment: Note that for the "c" files in /dev, we modeled it after another machine and only did g+w, or o+w or both based on the other machine; not always just both.

Comment: All I can think of would be to check the log files in /var/log for any errors related to issues reading/writing files.